# set vector drawable to imageview in XML

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a vector drawable. Here is `animation.xml` file

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">

    <group
        android:name="customGroup">

        <path
            android:fillColor="#64B5F6"
            android:fillAlpha="50"
            android:strokeColor="#64B5F6"
            android:strokeWidth="0.1"
            android:pathData="M0,0 C0.5,-8 5,0 10,-0.5 C13,-0.5 17,-8 18,0 L18.5,5 L0.1,5 Z"/>

        <path
            android:fillColor="#BBDEFB"
            android:fillAlpha="40"
            android:strokeWidth="0.1"
            android:strokeColor="#BBDEFB"
            android:pathData="M7.5,0 C8,-8 12,0 16,-0.5 C20,-1 22,-6 24,-1 L24,5 L7.5,4.97 Z"/>

        <path
            android:fillColor="#42A5F5"
            android:fillAlpha="50"
            android:strokeColor="#42A5F5"
            android:strokeWidth="0.1"
            android:pathData="M5,3 C6,-5.2 9.5,3 15,0 C18,-1 20,-9 22,3 L22.3,5 L5,4.95 Z"/>

    </group>

</vector>
```

[image: Here] is the image what i got with the above `animation.xml` file

I am trying to set this drawable to the image view in my `activity`. here is my `activity` layout file

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/animation" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Here] is what i am getting as output. It is working when i see the preview window. Getting problem only when i run the project.

Why that image getting cut on the top? Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the relative layout in some other layout ??

Comment: No. Relative layout is the main layout.

Comment: did you try wrap_content wrap_content instead ??

Comment: and you can also try android:background instead of src..

Comment: it is not working in both the ways...

Comment: same issue as before ?

Comment: yeah, having the same issue.  it is working fine in preview window. Problem only when i run the project.

Answer (score 0):

in your gradle file, first add this line

```
 android {
   defaultConfig {
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
 }
```

And then, replace your ImageView for this one instead

```
  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/animation" />
```

If it is still not working, you can keep those changes, and add the following line in an Aplication class (the one you extend from Aplication and then you declar it in your manifest)

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Still having the same issue

Comment: Did you try using the ScaleType attribute?

Comment: Yes. i tried with all possible scaleType values. Still having the issue. But it is working in the preview window.